# Okhttp Websocket, how to get the Socket instance created by its default SSLSocketFactory after connection?

Tags: websocket, okhttp

I need to have access to the instance of the Socket class created internally by the Okhttp WebSocket, but couldn't find any way to do such a thing.

I used the bellow code for creating the websocket:

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("example.com").build();
    WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
```

Is there any public method or private method using reflection to get the created Socket instance?

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked fine. Actually I have an implemented lib since before which needs to have the instance of the created socket of the connection. Newly switched to the okhttp and needed to pass this instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own subclass of SSLSocketFactory that delegates to a 'real' implementation. Then keep track of the socket instance you returned.